# go.mod unresolved dependency

Tags: go, heroku

i am using **1.14.2** version of go. i am trying to add my project to `go.mod` to deploy **heroku** by using `go mod init <dependecyname>`. After that i try to `go run main.go` command to run my project but i received following error:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/googollee/go-socket.io
go: finding module for package github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
go: finding module for package github.com/gorilla/mux
go: found github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go in github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
go: found github.com/googollee/go-socket.io in github.com/googollee/go-socket.io v1.4.4
go: found github.com/gorilla/mux in github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
controllers/userController.go:10:2: cannot find package
models/avatar.go:3:8: cannot find package
models/base.go:6:1: cannot find package
models/base.go:7:1: cannot find package
models/user.go:8:2: cannot find package
controllers/userController.go:11:2: cannot find package
controllers/userController.go:12:2: cannot find package
controllers/userController.go:13:2: cannot find package
```

and also after i investigated my `go.mod` file, i realized that there is unresolved dependency error in `require` block:

```
module <modulename>

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/googollee/go-socket.io v1.4.4 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0 // indirect
)
```

how to fix it?

Comment: 1. Your  module _must_ (no arguing here) a proper module name. Use  whatever you like but `<modulename>` is not  valid. Use "example.org/experiment" if you are  unsure what to use. 2. You _must_ (no arguing again here) import the packages in you module by there correct (read: full) import path: e.g. "example.org/experiment/models" or  however you named them. 3. Read How to Write Go Code and stick to  it. 4. `go mod init` must be called with the module name, not some dependency. 5. Never use `go run` with filename arguments.

Comment: I assume the author used a placeholder for module name and dependency, not the values above.

Comment: @Ali Gurelli were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: @sgauri yes but i couldn't remember how

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had the similar issue and I was able resolve by enabling the go modules integration. You can do that from Preferences > GO > GO Modules.

Comment: in addition that answer, you should be sure that installed golang version is equal with the version of go which specified in go.mod

Comment: Oh my!!! You saved my hours. Just switched to new project and can not understand why all is unresolved. Thanks

Comment: Such a simple fix but such a time saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I was able resolve this issue by turn off and on the go modules integration. GOLANG Preferences > GO > GO Modules.

Answer (score -1):

The `go init` command initializes the go module for the current project by adding a new `go.mod` file to your root folder with the module name you specified.
To add new dependencies to your project, use `go get <path>` and after that, it should be listed in the `go.mod` file.

Comment: it listed in go.mod file but as i mentioned on question it can't solve the dependency. it gives me unresolved dependency error. And also i tried to run my project then i give cannot find package error. when i removed the good file everything runs well but couldnt deploy heroku

Comment: In your `go.mod` only `indirect` dependencies are listed which means they were added there automatically when you built the module, this is slightly different from what you would get with an explicit `go get`. At this point, it's hard to say what "good" file you removed and what Heroku deploy says, so I would refer you to [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) as @Volker recommended.